# v-if using table row field and date range

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm trying to highlight a `<td>` based on that field's date range from today's date.

I've been trying to use current `<td>` date value less than `Date.now()` - #(number of days) to determine whether to highlight the `<td>` (green, yellow, or red) but not having any success with how I'm doing so.

```
<td v-if="props.item.date < Date.now() - 2">
  <v-icon small style="color:green;">fiber_manual_record</v-icon>{{ props.item.date }}
</td>
<td v-else-if="props.item.date < Date.now() - 7">
  <v-icon small style="color:yellow;">fiber_manual_record</v-icon>{{ props.item.date }}
</td>   
<td v-else>
  <v-icon small style="color:red;">fiber_manual_record</v-icon>{{ props.item.date }}
</td>
```

I'd like to think I'm close to the solution but I may not be doing it the appropriate way. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE 2**

```
<td v-if="Date.parse(props.item.date) > Date.now()">
   <v-icon small class="greenDate">fiber_manual_record</v-icon>{{ props.item.date_sent }}
</td>
<td v-else-if="Date.parse(props.item.date) < Date.now()">
   <v-icon small class="yellowDate">fiber_manual_record</v-icon>{{ props.item.date_sent }}
</td>   
<td v-else">
   <v-icon small class="redDate">fiber_manual_record</v-icon>{{ props.item.date_sent }}
</td>
```

Tried this just to test and see if anything is even recognized the conditions and it doesnt seem like it. Always hits the last condition (red). Maybe its not like `props.item.date` formatted `mm/dd/yyyy`. I also realized my conditions in the original example would conflict since I have both a less than 2 days and 7 days, but no condition for also greater than 2 days under 7 days condition

Comment: whats the format of props.item.date ???

Comment: Date Format -> mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: Updated the answer. Check that and let me know the result.

Comment: Added update edit above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Date.now() method returns the number of milliseconds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now)

So if you want to reduce somedays. you have to covert days to milliseconds and then minus. `1 day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1` milliseconds

[The Date.parse() method parses a string representation of a date, and returns the number of milliseconds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

Convert `props.item.date` to milliseconds using Date.parse

for example change code like below

```
<td v-if="Date.parse(props.item.date) < Date.now() - (2 * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)">
  <v-icon small style="color:green;">fiber_manual_record</v-icon>{{ props.item.date }}
</td>
<td v-else-if="Date.parse(props.item.date) < Date.now() - (7 * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)">
  <v-icon small style="color:yellow;">fiber_manual_record</v-icon>{{ props.item.date }}
</td>   
<td v-else>
  <v-icon small style="color:red;">fiber_manual_record</v-icon>{{ props.item.date }}
</td>
```

Comment: To add to this, in your code, when you do `Date.now() - 7` you're saying "older than 7 milliseconds ago", which, frankly, isn't that old.

Comment: Yea I figured I was off in that calculation

Comment: I figured it out, it was just how my date was being converted, so the comparison wasn't working. Thanks all